# iOS AdMob no ads after publishing on App Store

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob, ads

I have an app with AdMob. In plist I added apps ID and in code added banner ID.

```
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>ca-app-pub-XXXX~XXXX</string>
<key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
        <string>cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
</array>

bannerView.adUnitID = "YYYY/YYYY"
```

Test ads I can see, if I explicitly add `testDeviceIdentifiers`, otherwise I am getting an error  `To get test ads on this device, set: GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers`.

The App was published on the App Store few days ago. I was thinking AdMob can determine it and show the real Ads, but it did not happen. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the ads appeared after few days. Really weird that it took so much time.

Comment: look mine bout 10 days. I think its slow indexing. (might take some Timr to index couple millions of apps etc)